# How to stock the result of an execution of aggregation pipeline (using mongodb) in a variable

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wrote the following aggregation `MongoDB`:

```
 db.zips.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$city", total: {$sum: "$pop"}}}])
```

This command aggregates the total population of each city. I am working with the collection `zips` in the database `mapreduce`.

So now I don't know how to compare the speed of execution between the 2 pipelines on the collection `zips`. And also I don't know hot to stock the results in a variable and show them in terminal. 
And any ideas how to use `Date.now()` to measure the time?

I am new user of `MongoDB` and no way to understand it.

Comment: I found out how to use Date.now().
I need now to find out how to measure the speed of execution of the aggregation ??

Comment: Suppose your MongoDB server is V2.6+ and the client supports it well, add **explain** to `db.zips.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$city", total: {$sum: "$pop"}}}])`, i.e. `db.zips.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$city", total: {$sum: "$pop"}}}], {explain: true})`. Then you can get what you want.